# Prime-only tables of logarithms

Tags: soft-question, math-history

Two of the essential properties of logarithms are that
$$\log_a xy = \log_a x + \log_a y$$
and the property which follows from it
$$\log_a x^y = y \log_a x$$
Therefore, as long as you are willing to add, subtract and maybe multiply, you can get the logarithm of any composite number using the logarithm of its prime factors.

In the logarithm tables I've seen, however, the logarithms $\log_a x$ are listed out for $x=0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,...$ etc. in an arithmetic progression. This trades space (which would allow for more logarithms to be recorded, and hence greater range of numbers that could be calculated accurately) for speed and simplicity (avoiding the addition, subtraction, etc. to get the desired logarithm from its "prime factors").

I haven't yet seen a table with only primes. Did speed and convenience generally outweigh accuracy and information density, or is there more to the story?

Comment: Well, tables of logarithms were used for calculations. To know the factorization of a number, you would have to perform various divisions. To do those divisions, you would need a table of logarithms... And usually factorize a large  number is a pretty dificult problem.

Comment: Your idea works prefectly well. But the purpose of the "log" table is reduce the number of steps in a calculation.

Comment: Log tables were made to be used quickly with a reasonable level of precision.  The trade-off in space would have likely cost in both time and precision.

Comment: For example, to get $\log(0.03)$ using just logs of primes, you'd have to calculate $\log3-2\log2-2\log5$.

Comment: Yes, I know that several steps would be necessary. My point was that (as a minimum working example) if I only had room in my table for the first 5 non-composite integers and I wanted to calculate $\log 42$, then I would get a better result with $1,2,3,5,7$ using $\log 2 + \log 3 + \log 7$ than $1,2,3,4,5$. The point has been made, though, that the efficiency tradeoff isn't worth it, especially since it would introduce potential for error at intermediate steps.